# iOS user can't move accessibility focus to offscreen table cells (outside table's visible area)?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, accessibility, voiceover

In my iOS app I have a UITableView. It contains some UITableViewCells which are `isAccessibilityElement = true` and some which are `isAccessibilityElement = false`. (The latter are cells that contain only separator lines; I don't want these read by VoiceOver.)

If there's a nonaccessible cell (`= false`) at the bottom of the table's visible area, then I can't "swipe past" it to get to an accessible table cell beyond that. Instead, right-swiping will move accessibility focus from a visible table cell to some other visible UI element. Similarly, if there's a nonaccessible cell at the top of the table's visible area, then I can't left-"swipe past" it to get to an accessible cell above it.

I was hoping to be able to swipe-left and swipe-right through all of the accessible cells in the table, and have them scroll into view as they received focus. I tried overriding `accessibilityElementDidBecomeFocused` in the hopes of then using `scrollToItem`, but it looks like it never gets focus, so this is never called.

Is there any way I can get iOS to send focus to each accessible table element in turn, whether or not it's currently in view? Or is there some guideline which says that accessibility should only handle UI elements that are currently visible?

Comment: any success? I have a similar issue

Comment: No, I never found an answer to this.

Answer (score -2):

**The problem:** UI reuse cells, as a result accessibility tree can'n fetch data from UI and has no information about every cell in datasource and can't search for next header.

**Solution:** provide explicit description for every cell by overriding data at `accessibilityElements`. [Link to repository](https://github.com/akaDuality/RotorHeaders)

Comment: I think I was able to swipe through the table as long as there weren't inaccessible cells in the way, so your observation about reuse cells doesn't seem like it applies here. I don't remember whether I tried `accessibilityElements`. I also don't understand how the repository you linked to is supposed to help, specifically.